# How to handel event onChange of react-date-range (Date range) when only select start date or end date

Tags: reactjs, date-range, react-date-range

1. I have a component DateRange using react-date-range ,
   Import :

```
import { Range, DateRange, RangeKeyDict } from 'react-date-range';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css';
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css';
```

Default value :

```
 const [dateRangeValue, setDateRangeValue] = useState<Range>({
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
    });
```

Fuction :

```
const handelOnchange = (itemRespon: Range): void => {
        console.log('itemRespon,', itemRespon);
        //Display start end date which was chosen
        renderFooteDate(itemRespon);
        //Set new date range value
        setDateRangeValue(itemRespon);
        //CallBackParrent to give data back
    };
```

Component :

```
 <DateRange
 className={style.dateRangeWrapper}
 editableDateInputs={true}
 onChange={(item: RangeKeyDict): void => handelOnchange(item.selection)}
 moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
 ranges={[{ ...dateRangeValue, key: 'selection' }]}
 months={2}
 direction="horizontal"
 />
```

Picture :
[Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXyST.png)

2.I hope i can get value when ever i chose only start date or end date , but currently it only active onChange event when i click both start and end date. I do not always need both start and end , sometimes i just need 1 of them is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error, but it works fine for me.
[Please see example](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-spence-kw3og?file=/src/App.tsx).
The only thing you have to do is to press *Enter* after changing the date, then the changes will be applied.

Comment: thank you for your example ,but i think it not the one i need . I think i have to custom and make a new one to fit my requirement